# How to select the first n elements in XPath

Tags: html, xml, xpath, web-scraping, yql

I am using YQL to scrape some images from a website.

The problem is I want only the first 5 images from that website.

I have the following query:

```
select * from html where url="http://myanimelist.net/anime/9253/Steins;Gate" and xpath='//img[position()<=5]'
```

But, it is returning all image elements instead of the first 5.

YQL console: [open YQL console with above XPath](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+*+from+html+where+url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fmyanimelist.net%2Fanime%2F9253%2FSteins%3BGate%22+and+xpath%3D'%2F%2Fimg%5Bposition()%3C%3D5%5D')

Is there anything wrong with my XPath query ?

PS: I cannot use `LIMIT 5` since I may need to scrape some other tags too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This XPath expression will select the first 5 `img` elements:**

```
//img[count(preceding::img) < 5]
```

**Here's the whole YQL query:**

```
select * from html where url="http://myanimelist.net/anime/9253/Steins;Gate" and xpath='//img[count(preceding::img) < 5]'
```

**You can watch it work on the [YQL Console](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+*+from+html+where+url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fmyanimelist.net%2Fanime%2F9253%2FSteins%3BGate%22+and+xpath%3D'%2F%2Fimg%5Bcount(preceding%3A%3Aimg)+%3C+5%5D'%0A).**

Comment: Wow, thats a neat little trick with preceding. I knew I had to use ``count()`` somehow but I was trying with ``self`` instead of ``preceding`` .