# Get first n entries from rss or atom feed using YQL and feednormalizer

Tags: xml, xpath, rss, yql, atom-feed

I'm using YQL to retrieve RSS and ATOM feeds as JSON, and normalize them to ATOM style using the feednormalizer table.

[`select * from feednormalizer where output='atom_1.0' AND url='http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/rss/msuweb'`](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+*+from+feednormalizer+where+output%3D'atom_1.0'+AND+url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.delicious.com%2Fv2%2Frss%2Fmsuweb')

I need to get only the first X entries. I know that, in theory, [an xpath expression should be able to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26221654/how-to-select-the-first-n-elements-in-xpath). However, when I try one that I assume ought to work...

[`select * from feednormalizer where output='atom_1.0' AND url='http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/rss/msuweb' AND xpath='//entry[count(preceding::entry) < 5]'`](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+*+from+feednormalizer+where+output%3D'atom_1.0'+AND+url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.delicious.com%2Fv2%2Frss%2Fmsuweb'+and+xpath%3D'%2F%2Fentry%5Bcount(preceding%3A%3Aentry)+%3C+5%5D')

...the results object comes back null. I've also tried [using item instead of entry](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+*+from+feednormalizer+where+output%3D'atom_1.0'+AND+url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.delicious.com%2Fv2%2Frss%2Fmsuweb'+and+xpath%3D'%2F%2Fitem%5Bcount(preceding%3A%3Aitem)+%3C+5%5D') in the xpath query, since that's what an RSS feed will have in the actual XML. That also returns a null results object.

### Other Stuff I've Tried

#### Limits

I've also tried using [both local and remote limits](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/paging.html), which returns the same number of entries as if I hadn't specified a limit.

[`select * from feednormalizer(0,5) where output='atom_1.0' AND url='http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/rss/msuweb'`](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+*+from+feednormalizer(0%2C5)+where+output%3D'atom_1.0'+AND+url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.delicious.com%2Fv2%2Frss%2Fmsuweb')

[`select * from feednormalizer where output='atom_1.0' AND url='http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/rss/msuweb' limit 6`](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+*+from+feednormalizer+where+output%3D'atom_1.0'+AND+url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.delicious.com%2Fv2%2Frss%2Fmsuweb'+limit+6)

#### Selecting Columns with CrossProduct

Notably, I still need all the metadata that comes with the typical `select *` query. That is, I need the feed's title, link, etc., and I'd prefer they stayed at the root element. So, I know that I can do

`select title, link, entry from feednormalizer(0,6) where output='atom_1.0' AND url='http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/rss/msuweb'`

or

`select title, link, entry from feednormalizer where output='atom_1.0' AND url='http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/rss/msuweb' limit 6`

But that puts the title and feed link directly onto each entry in the list, even with [`crossProduct=optimized`](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/optimizing_response.html#optimizing_response-configuring) in the URL string. Call me picky, but I'd rather not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Might be really late but for others like me that had the same question, I finished by doing 2 requests. The first one for meta data:

```
select * from feednormalizer 
where output='atom_1.0' 
AND url='http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/rss/msuweb'
```

and the second one to limit the data:

```
select title, link, entry 
from feednormalizer(0,6) 
where output='atom_1.0' 
AND url='http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/rss/msuweb'
```

! Not optimized but works !